# Lazy evaluation and deadlocks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concurrency, deadlock, lazy-evaluation

Recently I decided to give a try and started to read book "Fast Data Processing Systems with SMACK stack" by Raul Estrada. After 2 first chapters I thought that it is not-so-bad compilation of "hello worlds" unless I've encountered that:

> As we saw, lazy evaluation also prevents deadlocks and bottlenecks, because it prevents a
>   process waiting for the outcome of another process indefinitely.

I was struck with surprise and tried to find any argumentation for that claim that lazy evaluation prevents deadlock. That statement was in regard to Scala and Spark. Unfortunately I didn't find any arguments. As far as I know in order to avoid deadlock you have to ensure that at least one of those will never happen:

- Mutual exclusion
- Lock & wait
- No preemption
- Circular wait

How lazy evaluation can prevent any of them?

Answer (score 2):

Lazy evaluation per se doesn't prevent deadlocks, it is however closely tied to another concept, which is computation graph. Since Spark describes computations as a lineage of dependencies, it can verify that the computation graph is acyclic (famous DAG), therefore there are no cases which might cause circular wait.

At the high level Spark enforces this by disallowing nested transformations and actions, which means, that there no hidden dependencies between stages.

Answer (score 1):

The core data structure of Spark i.e `RDD` is immutable, as a String object in Java. Every time a transformation is applied on an existing `RDD` a new `RDD` gets created. This new `RDD` is represented as a vertex and the applied transformation is represented by a directed edge from the parent `RDD` to the new `RDD`. In Lazy Evaluation Spark core adds a new vertex to the DAG every time we apply a transformation on an existing `RDD`. Spark doesn't executes the transformations right away, an action call triggers the evaluation of `RDDs`, which is done by executing the DAG (lineage of that particular `RDD`, on which the **action** is called). Lazy evaluation makes it impossible to have directed cycles in the lineage graphs of `RDDs`. Hene possibility of Spark driver getting stuck in an infinite loop is zero. this is what lazy evaluation in Spark is.
Lazy evaluation implementation with DAGs adds benefits of query optimization and fault tolerance in Spark

Now, when it comes to the Deadlock prevention and preventing Mutual exclusion, Lock & wait, No preemption, Circular wait, Which is all about scheduling tasks and allocating resources properly. I think this is a concern of Spark execution environment. Spark Driver does the scheduling of executors processes as they execute the tasks in the worker nodes of the cluster manager.